# How to solve the {code: UNAUTHENTICATED, details: null, message: UNAUTHENTICATED}) error using Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am currently facing the above mentioned error when using the cloud_functions dependency on my Flutter app. My function https call is as follows:

```
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions(region: "region name").getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'function-name')..timeout = const Duration(seconds:30);
```

And my function invocation within the code is as given below:

```
onPressed: () async {
  try {
    dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'message':'hello!',
      'url': urlController.text,
    });
    setState(() {
      imgurl = resp.data['image'];
      time = resp.data['timestamp'];
   });
```

I have added the ID I am using for authentication to my function via the console IAM. Unfortunately, I still keep receiving the following error:

```
PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: UNAUTHENTICATED, details: null, message: UNAUTHENTICATED})
```

How can I resolve that?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I guess that your function is deployed in private mode? Is your user authenticated?

Comment: My user is authenticated. I don't know about private mode though, but I defined the function to allow only authenticated requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deployed your function in "private mode", I mean, allow only authenticated user, you have to add a valid identity_token in the header of your request.

You have [an example here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating), mostly on end user because it's your use case. Don't use a service account key file because your flutter app is public and you will share your secret publicly.

You can also use Cloud Endpoint with Firebase authentication mode. I [wrote an article for setting up an authentication with API key](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1). Simply [update the authentication mode](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) and it will works.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I first tried a test run by excluding all authentication permissions via the IAM, yet it still shows the error. Why would the same error come up if allUsers has been included in the CF Invokers?

Comment: I went through the first link, but I didn't quite get the "Include the ID token in an Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN header in the request to the function." statement. Where should I include this header as part of my code? Thanks once more for your help.

Comment: It's not normal if you have allowed "allUsers" to your Cloud Functions to continue to have authentication issue. Did you try to deploy again your function? with the param --allow-unauthenticated?

Comment: Sadly, I never developed in Flutter and I can't help you for the header part....

Comment: Oh, I didn't redeploy the function per se. I created the function first with allow unauthenticated (when it showed the not found error, then unauthenticated error, then internal error) then changed it to allow authenticated only (for which it failed, even though I had authenticated the user), then added all users back to my function Invokers list, when it failed again. So I'm lost on how this works - why should it show the same message for a function allowing unauthenticated users! No worries for the header part. I figured out how to add it to my function invocation.

Comment: Did you set some special ingress param to your function?

Comment: No, I haven't. By the way, the issue with unauthenticated cloud functions showing that message went away - it just needed a refresh.... To be honest, I'm facing a host of other errors with Cloud Functions, I might just switch to Cloud Run or App Engine at this point. I believe that's your preferred resource too.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Cloud Run. However, the underlying infrastructure is the same as the Cloud Function. And thus, the security policy is also the same! App Engine is not my fav, IMO, Cloud Run will overwrite it

Comment: however, you can also call you function without the functions library!! It's a simple HTTP call to an URL, as any other API!

Comment: Don't Url calls also need authentication? Sorry if my questions seem too novice, I'm too new to APIs and working with cloud stuff. I've read about Cloud Run being superior to App Engine too, or rather App Engine being overkill.

Comment: You don't need authentication to call Cloud Function, Cloud Run or App Engine URL. However, ifyou want to protect your service and protect your resources (and your money) it's strongly recommended to secure your endpoints. Cloud Endpoints is a good tool for this. and it allows to reuse firebase authentication to access to secured endpoint.

Comment: By the way @Guillaume, I'm just dipping my toes into Cloud Run, and Docker in general. Are there any good tutorials/guides out there that you could suggest? Thanks

Comment: The [cloud run documentation page is a good starting point](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) with an hello world in the most common language and framework, with dockerfile examples.